# Do mailto links count as backlinks for Google PageRank purposes?

Tags: seo, backlinks, pagerank

I want link to another site with an email like `admin@example.com`.  So the link will have the `href=mailto:admin@example.com`.

Does that count as a backlink to `example.com` and transfer any Google PageRank?

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**

The `mailto:` links are considered as normal links and are never considered as backlinks and do not transfer any Google PageRank.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, however it would be a better answer if you said how you know this.  Have you done experiments, or can you link to sources?

Comment: I have experimented myself and have never found it to be a factor to affect the PageRank. This experiment was carried out few months prior to this answer but I do not have any sources to validate this or provide you accurate information right now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

NO.

It is type of email link, it is not direct site link subtype (back link).

Comment: This answer doesn't say anything new compared to other answers.

Comment: Because there is nothing new in the field of linking perhaps.